# Multiple Queues in Kannel?

Tags: web-services, security, jakarta-ee, sms-gateway, kannel

Hi i am  using kannel in one of my projects and i want to know how to be able to implement multiple queues in the push mode.
For the pull mode i checked some posts and found out that kannel does not implement any mecanism of queuing for the outcoming SMS, because the system should resist in the high load scenarios.

I a very new at kannel. i've tried their documentation but so far did not get the main idea for the push mode. 
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on sqlbox to implement multiple queues before tapping on bearerbox for delivering MT traffic.

Install sqlbox and run 2 instances, each one is connected on a different couple of sql tables, let's say:

1. queued_1 and sent_1
2. queued_2 and sent_2

And then you'll have to insert your SMS-MT into queued_1 and queued_2 tables with a roundrobin algorithm so you can load-share the traffic on both sqlboxes.

But dont get it wrong, bearerbox still have its own queue, and it's a one-queue-per-smsc, this is a memory based queue which gets filled whenever the smsc doesnt respond (with submit_sm_resp) or rejects delivery.

Comment: Just one question, how much possible queues i can define and how much traffic could take one queue ? and also how much do you recommend for a system with high traffic ? thank you for your previous answer it was very helpfull

Comment: Hi !
How much traffic it can handle on one queue depends on how much transaction your cpu can make at first, how much network throughput you get on the wire between kannel and the smsc at second and how much submit_sm the smsc can handle at third.

The bearerbox queue get filled when your cpu processing is higher than what your network or smsc can handle, so for example, if you can insert in your sql table queues at 200 MPS (message per second) when your network or smsc can only handle 120 MPS, the bearerbox queue will get filled at a 80 MPS rate.